# Calling SetParent stops a form using the modern window colours

Tags: .net, winapi

I call these User32.DLL API calls to embed a windows forms form as a child window of another window...

```
SetWindowLong(frm.Handle.ToInt32, GWL_STYLE, WS_CHILD Or WS_DLGFRAME Or WS_BORDER)
SetParent(frm.Handle.ToInt32, m_intOldParent)
```

I've noticed in windows 8 that the style of these windows that have had SetParent called look a bit odd, they seem to be using the old SystemColors.ActiveCaption and SystemColors.ActiveCaptionGradient colours to display the Titlebar and not the new Windows 8 colour.

This makes my child windows look a bit odd.

Anyone any ideas how I can get the windows 8 style in my child windows?

NOTE: Think it's also the same in windows 7 too.

Many thanks

Comment: I expect it's because it's no longer a top level window so DWM doesn't come into play.

Comment: Are you hosting the window in a different process?

Comment: Not a separate process! (Not sure what you mean though)

Answer (score 0):

What I've ended up doing is this:

- Set the form I'm opening to have no border
- A second "host" form has that also has no border but has some labels and buttons around the edges that looks a bit like the Win7/Win8
  title bar and the windows close button.
- Add the first form to a panel on the host form (Docked to fill inside the panel)
- Added some code on mouse down to allow the user to resize the form using the form edges

Also I stopped using the SetWindowLong API call and just did this:

```
ParentForm.Controls.Add(ChildForm)
```

This seemed to work a bit better with less odd side effects regarding focus and which window is activated.